# How to edit blue outline border on embedded form input field

Tags: wordpress, forms

I embedded a form from Flodesk on to my site and would like to edit the focus outline border, which is currently blue, but can't find the correct css selector for it.  The form editor did not have any 'custom css' input areas or customization of the focus outline.  Is the best way to edit the outline by adding in some html syle css in the embedded html code?

For example :

```
<div id="fd-form-6362f1a99bbdd5d8546029aa" style="width:300px;padding:0px !important;margin-right:100px;"></div>
<script>
  window.fd('form', {
    formId: '6362f1a99bbdd5d8546029aa',
    containerEl: '#fd-form-6362f1a99bbdd5d8546029aa'
  });
</script>
```

This is my embedded code for the form.  How would I add the css in here so that I can remove/edit the focus outline border?

So far, I've tried opening dev tools and copying the css selectors there and adding in

`example_selector:focus{ outline: none !important; }`

Comment: Could you share the link of the page, it would be easier?

Comment: @C0G1T0 I ended up figuring it out.  The css selectors of the class kept changing every time I would tab through each input field, so I just had to add the focused part to the end of the class to select it.  So the css selector ended up being `fd-form-6362f1a99bbdd5d8546029aa-focus-visible` .